# How do I remove the blur effect from a popover view in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm displaying a `UIPopoverView` in my app, and I want it to have a transparent color, but without any blurring effect. If I set the `popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`, I can see that the blur effect is there, even with no color.

Does anybody know how I can remove the blur effect?

In case it helps, here's my prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier != nil {
        if segue.identifier! == "toSetTags" {
            if let destination = segue.destination as? SetTagsViewController {
                if let controller = destination.popoverPresentationController {
                    destination.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height / 2)

                    controller.barButtonItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
                    controller.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    controller.permittedArrowDirections = .any
                    controller.delegate = self

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
popoverPresentationController.contentViewController.view.alpha = 0
```

Comment: popoverPresentationController doesn't have a property contentViewController. I'm using Swift 3 - maybe the name changed?

Comment: If you mean popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController.view.alpha = 0, that doesn't work... same as setting the alpha in the popover view controller's view in IB.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the code to the AppDelegate.swift file or anywhere the app is getting initialized.

```
    let appearance = UIVisualEffectView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [NSClassFromString("_UIPopoverStandardChromeView")! as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type])
    appearance.effect = UIVisualEffect()
```